--dev flag seems to be broken on export
I'm trying to use expo's export function to create something servable that uses dev mode so that I can have logic that is exclusive to development mode. However, trying to do so causes errors:
Export with and without --dev
As you can see, without --dev, it creates the files. With --dev, it looks like it attempts to write the files to a directory that is double my project directory. Why is this happening?
I tried running it with --dev and that failed. -dev didn't seem to create servable files with the DEV boolean available. Moving the --dev flag also didn't seem to do anything.

I've spent the better part of today struggling with the same issue with no luck.  Tried clearing everything node_module related, build cache, checking that metro is resolving paths correctly, and can't make heads nor tails of the situation..
